# What is the correct sequence in which cflock releases when using multiple locks in different functions?

Tags: coldfusion, synchronization, locking

Given the following scenario, I would like to know if functionOneLock releases itself before functionTwoLock is triggered, or does it wait until functionTwoLock releases first?

```
<!--- functionOne() --->
<cffunction name="functionOne">
<cflock name="functionOneLock" type="exclusive">
   <!--- do something --->
   <cfset functionTwo()>
</cflock>
</cffunction>

<!--- functionTwo() --->
<cffunction name="functionTwo">
<cflock name="functionTwoLock" type="exclusive">
   <!--- do something here --->
</cflock>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are calling `functionOne()` from `functionTwo()`, like so:

```
<!--- functionOne() --->
<cffunction name="functionOne">
<cflock name="functionOneLock" type="exclusive">
   <!--- do something --->
   <cfset functionTwo() />
</cflock>
</cffunction>
```

Since you are using named locks, your thread of execution will enter `functionOneLock` then within that call the other function thus entering `functionTwoLock`. It will then complete the code within that lock before returning from that function and completing `functionOneLock`.

So to answer your question `functionOneLock` will have to wait for `functionTwoLock` to complete.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ciaran, a small question, is there a way to trigger the second function but not wait for it to complete? Would I have to include the <cfset functionTwo()> in a <cfthread> tag?

Comment: Yes, if you use multi-threading you can do this. You can use `cfthread` to kick off a thread and the calling code will not wait for that thread, it is a totally separate process. If you do this just keep an eye on your thread settings in CF admin!